# Web developer wanting to learn iPhone app development

Tags: iphone

I am a web developer who is looking to get started building iPhone apps. I have experience with PHP so programming isn't completely foreign to me. In what order should I learn the iPhone languages? Should I start with C or just start off with Objective-C? After I learn objective-c where should I go next? Any books or other learning materials you guys suggest would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: C is a good foundation even outside of iphone.  Time well spent.  concerning iOS I like the zdiarski iphone SDK book because it has you understand it from code.  Most iOS books have a primer in objective-C which is good enough of you know C ...

Comment: The Stanford university iOS courses are great too. And free!

Comment: "The Stanford university iOS courses" +1 :D

Answer (score 6):

Yes, definitely get yourself a provisioning profile at apple, download the sample apps and just start messing around. I did that in the beginning of this year and now I'm just thrilled with the progress. This website stack overflow will help you a lot... type questions and watch people literally trying to help you. It's great.
The way we deal with variables and functions is very different so keep an open mind about that, how to transfer variables, or why should you have so many files where before you could get along with one PHP file  but it's all worth it. Once you understand it gets awesome just like with PHP.
Glad to see another "immigrant" like me...

Here's some websites that can also help:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/category/tutorials/iphone/

http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000086.php   //core data class overview. You're gonna have to learn Core-data which is very different then SQL but works wonderfully.

Another one... On iTunes look for developing apps for ios from Stanford University videos. You're gonna wish you could thank those guys face - to - face.

Best of luck !
I would vote up your question but I don't have 15 reputation just yet. lol.

Comment: Great answer. +1 to put you over the 15. :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been waiting for about a week for that to happen. LMAO!